# Sequence diagram UML 2.0 questions

Tags: uml, sequence, diagram

I have a couple of questions regarding sequence diagrams and was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction.

This is the diagram I have come up with so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyF01.png

I am unsure however if this is correct.

The following is the questions I have regarding this diagram, and sequence diagrams in general:

First off, I am wondering if I need a loop at all since adding another employer is not pragmatic but rather dependent upon the user clicking "add another employer" on a dialogue that is displayed.

If a loop is required, is there a way to properly specify a do while loop? because the diagram looks slightly confusing with a loop condition "while add another employer" yet add another employer is determined within the "if detailsValid" section after calling "displayAddAnotherEmployer()"

If I have a condition such as the "save employer details" condition, do I still need to show the employer liaison officer clicking the save employer details and interacting with the view? or is this implied by the if condition?

Can actors have an execution on their lifeline?

Lastly, in the "else if cancel" condition, do I need a "break" with a condition "if add another employer" or is that implied when the view is closed?

Thanks for taking the time to read this and any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: A second version of the same diagram, which one is clearer?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BlgX.png

Comment: When creating the employer the details the user has input are passed in via the constructor by the way. I just haven't had time to specify that.

Comment: You should use the edit link to update your question instead of adding a comment. Anyhow, don't put too many sub-questions in. SO is meant as a single question/single answer platform.

Answer (score 1):

You should not over-use sequence diagrams with respect to algorithmic details. Back in the 80s we thought that graphical programming would be the future. So now we know it's simply scrap. Though a picture can say more than 1000 words in many cases programming languages tell us this is not true in call cases. How long did you spend to create that diagram? And how long would it take to write a few words in a meta-language?

You can/should use fragments if you have some kind of a more global dependency which should be highlighted. Again, don't start using nested fragments. Better use two diagrams and eventually diagram gates to highlight the two (or more) effects of the nested loops.

Now for the other conditions: if things are obvious you do not need to show details. Often a simple note helps more than an over-constructed sequence diagram.

Actors can well be life lines. Just instantiate any actor and it can send messages to objects (click mouse, enter keys, etc.).

For the `else-if` just see what I said above.